# Are optimizations used under .net 8 for a .net Standard project

Tags: .net, performance

I have a .net Standard library on .net5. If I upgrade to 7,8 (which have big performance changes) will it use all the compiler optimizations for speed that are in those Frameworks to generate the Standard Lib ? I realize no new interfaces are available to the Standard lib.